# Filter in array reference in markup using angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I keep running into situations where I have a directive (A) that takes a list of items and then passes a subset of those items into another directive (B) but in order to do this I always have to watch the original list in directive A's controller, filter it into a new array, and assign it to a new variable on my scope.

I know you can do `{{ myList | filter:'!propertyName'}}` but you can't use that same expression when you are using another directive's reference (`=`).

Is there a way of doing this in just the template or just a better way of doing it?

Here is an example:

In this case "iterable" uses the keyboard to iterate over the items it is supplied. I don't want to be able select an item if it is disabled so I want to remove that from the list the iterable directive uses.

```
<div class="list-directive">
   <iterable items="items" active="activeItem" disabled="enableKeyboardIteration"></iterable>
   <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{disabled: item.disabled, active: activeItem == item}" ng-mouseenter="makeItemActive(item)">
     {{item.name}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you give a working example of this scenario please. It would be useful to see in code your current approach.

Comment: I've added the example to the question.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with your question / example understanding what it is you're trying to achieve ... but i'm sure i could help you

Comment: I am simply trying to pass a subset of items to another directive without having to do a $watch on the original list of items and create another array in my controller.